# Refinement mapping

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Good evening,

When I read Cech cohomology in *Riemann surfaces* written by Otto Forster, I see the following proposition : Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathfrak{F}$ a sheaf of abelian groups on $X.$ Let $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ be open coverings of $X$ such that $\mathfrak{B}$ is finer than $\mathfrak{A}.$ Then the induced mapping by the refinement mapping $t^{\mathfrak{A}}_{\mathfrak{B}}\colon H^1(\mathfrak{A}, \mathfrak{F})\to H^1(\mathfrak{B},\mathfrak{F})$ is injective.

So, my question : Is this induced mapping injective at the higher orders of cohomology?